# How to access parent global variable in child process nodejs

Tags: node.js, child-process

I have the following code:

```
import ChildProcess = require("child_process");
global.abc = "token";
ChildProcess.spawn("node", [path.join(process.cwd(), "./install-db.js")]);
```

**install-db.js** in this file I am not able to get global variable, How should I use **global.abc** in this child process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As child process is a separate entity, you can't excess your main process's global variable inside it.

Though there are ways to send data/inputs to child processes. You can use `command line arguments` to send data to child process.

> Read more about passing arguments to child process: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options

Comment: Thanks :)
It worked

ChildProcess.spawn("node", [path.join(process.cwd(), "./install-db.js"), global.abc]);

Used it like this
process.argv[2]